# Getting a list of associative array keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an associative array in JavaScript:

```
var dictionary = {
    "cats": [1,2,3,4,5],
    "dogs": [6,7,8,9,10]
};
```

How do I get this dictionary's keys? I.e., I want

```
var keys = ["cats", "dogs"];
```

---

Just to get the terminology correct - there is no such thing as an 'associative array' in JavaScript - this is technically just an `object` and it is the object keys we want.

Comment: Simple way with lodash JS - https://lodash.com/docs#keys

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the terminology! Can you maybe make that a bit bigger in bright red blinking lights?

Comment: @Joe I'll make it the first result in google for you when I get a chance

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can use: `Object.keys(obj)`

Example:

```js
var dictionary = {
  "cats": [1, 2, 37, 38, 40, 32, 33, 35, 39, 36],
  "dogs": [4, 5, 6, 3, 2]
};

// Get the keys
var keys = Object.keys(dictionary);

console.log(keys);
```

See reference below for browser support. It is supported in Firefox 4.20, Chrome 5, and Internet Explorer 9. *[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)* contains a code snippet that you can add if `Object.keys()` is not supported in your browser.

Comment: I'm switching this to the accepted answer now. Only IE8 doesn't support it anymore (for which a polyfill is available https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 383):

Try this:

```
var keys = [];
for (var key in dictionary) {
  if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    keys.push(key);
  }
}
```

`hasOwnProperty` is needed because it's possible to insert keys into the prototype object of `dictionary`. But you typically don't want those keys included in your list.

For example, if you do this:

```
Object.prototype.c = 3;
var dictionary = {a: 1, b: 2};
```

and then do a `for...in` loop over `dictionary`, you'll get `a` and `b`, but you'll also get `c`.

Comment: No need to declare "var keys = []", unless you need to use it after the loop.

Comment: @mzalazar, you better do or it'll be a global variable, which is bad practice.

Comment: @b00t i though that by declaring a variable inside a for loop... it wouln't be set in global space... now you made me doubt hehe  :)

Comment: @mzalazar, but you're not declaring it (**keys**) at any point if you're just using `keys.push(key);`. You're just pulling (and thus declaring it) from the global namespace. :)

Answer (score 184):

```
for (var key in dictionary) {
  // Do something with key
}
```

It's the [for..in statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/for...in).

Comment: Just noticed that there should be a colon instead of a comma between "dogs" and the array above. Assume it's due to transcription.

Comment: Very important to check for `dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)` otherwise you may end up with methods from the prototype chain..

Comment: From the same article: _Iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in arbitrary order_. If key order is important, you need to do something like pushing them in an array, sorting it, and then using a for() loop to get keys from the sorted array with which to index the original object.

Comment: It is, of course, fair to optimize by omitting the dictionary.hasOwnProperty check if you can be confident that the object lacks a prototype. But it's important to be aware of the possibility of prototype inheritance in this context, since JavaScript dictionaries are really objects.

Answer (score 16):

Just a quick note. Be wary of using `for..in` if you use a library ([jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), [Prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_JavaScript_Framework), etc.), as most of them add methods to created Objects (including dictionaries).

This will mean that when you loop over them, method names will appear as keys. If you are using a library, look at the documentation and look for an enumerable section, where you will find the right methods for iteration of your objects.

Answer (score 3):

Simple jQuery way:

This is what I use:

DictionaryObj being the JavaScript dictionary object you want to go through. And value, key of course being the names of them in the dictionary.

```
$.each(DictionaryObj, function (key, value) {
    $("#storeDuplicationList")
        .append($("<li></li>")
        .attr("value", key)
        .text(value));
});
```

Comment: this requires jQuery (which is fine) but you forgot to mention it :-)

Comment: @Exzile The argument names in your function definition are very confusing. It says at https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ that the callback is Function( String propertyName, Object valueOfProperty ).  Your names imply the reverse.

Comment: @Chris I will update that for you. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using [Rob de la Cruz's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558981/getting-a-list-of-associative-array-keys/9539168#9539168):

```
Object.keys(obj)
```

And in a file loaded early on I have some lines of code **borrowed from elsewhere on the Internet** which cover the case of old versions of script interpreters that do not have Object.keys built in.

```
if (!Object.keys) {
    Object.keys = function(object) {
        var keys = [];
        for (var o in object) {
            if (object.hasOwnProperty(o)) {
                keys.push(o);
            }
        }
        return keys;
    };
}
```

I think this is the best of both worlds for large projects: simple modern code and backwards compatible support for old versions of browsers, etc.

Effectively it puts JW's solution into the function when Rob de la Cruz's
Object.keys(obj) is not natively available.