# How can I get the key value in a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

How do I get the key value in a JSON object and the length of the object using JavaScript?

For example:

```
[
  {
    "amount": " 12185",
    "job": "GAPA",
    "month": "JANUARY",
    "year": "2010"
  },
  {
    "amount": "147421",
    "job": "GAPA",
    "month": "MAY",
    "year": "2010"
  },
  {
    "amount": "2347",
    "job": "GAPA",
    "month": "AUGUST",
    "year": "2010"
  }
]
```

Here, length of this array is 3. For getting, value is fine `([0].amount)`, in index`[0]` it has three name value pairs.

So, I need to get the name (like amount or job... totally four name) and also how do I count how many names there are?

Comment: That’s not valid JSON as the keys aren’t quoted.

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558981/iterating-through-list-of-keys-for-associative-array-in-json

Comment: thanks for all, given your answers.

Comment: use `jQuery` and `getJSON` method.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First off, you're not dealing with a "JSON object." You're dealing with a JavaScript object. JSON is a *textual* notation, but if your example code works (`[0].amount`), you've already deserialized that notation into a JavaScript object graph. (What you've quoted isn't valid JSON at all; in [JSON](http://json.org), the keys must be in double quotes. What you've quoted is a JavaScript object literal, which is a superset of JSON.)

> Here, length of this array is 2.

No, it's 3.

> So, i need to get the name (like amount or job... totally four name) and also to count how many names are there?

If you're using an environment that has full ECMAScript5 support, you can use `Object.keys` ([spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.keys) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)) to get the enumerable keys for one of the objects as an array. If not (or if you just want to loop through them rather than getting an array of them), you can use `for..in`:

```
var entry;
var name;
entry = array[0];
for (name in entry) {
    // here, `name` will be "amount", "job", "month", then "year" (in no defined order)
}
```

Full working example:

```js
(function() {
  
  var array = [
    {
      amount: 12185,
      job: "GAPA",
      month: "JANUARY",
      year: "2010"
    },
    {
      amount: 147421,
      job: "GAPA",
      month: "MAY",
      year: "2010"
    },
    {
      amount: 2347,
      job: "GAPA",
      month: "AUGUST",
      year: "2010"
    }
  ];
  
  var entry;
  var name;
  var count;
  
  entry = array[0];
  
  display("Keys for entry 0:");
  count = 0;
  for (name in entry) {
    display(name);
    ++count;
  }
  display("Total enumerable keys: " + count);

  // === Basic utility functions
  
  function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = msg;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
  
})();
```

Since you're dealing with raw objects, the above `for..in` loop is fine (unless someone has committed the sin of mucking about with `Object.prototype`, but let's assume not). But if the object you want the keys from may also inherit enumerable properties from its prototype, you can restrict the loop to only the object's *own* keys (and not the keys of its prototype) by adding a `hasOwnProperty` call in there:

```
for (name in entry) {
  if (entry.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    display(name);
    ++count;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's also advisable to check that the property isn't coming from the prototype. Inside the for loop use if (entry.hasOwnProperty(name)) {... do stuff...}

Comment: @Darren: Yeah, I just added a note about that although in this case it's completely unnecessary unless someone is mucking about with `Object.prototype`, which they **really shouldn't be**.

Answer (score 47):

JSON content is basically represented as an associative array in JavaScript. You just need to loop over them to either read the key or the value:

```
    var JSON_Obj = { "one":1, "two":2, "three":3, "four":4, "five":5 };

    // Read key
    for (var key in JSON_Obj) {
       console.log(key);
       console.log(JSON_Obj[key]);
   }
```

Comment: how to find the length of "JsonObj"?

Comment: What if i  wanna get Value into For loop ?*

Comment: Oh its very easy. As told its an associate array i.e dictionary. You will do the same thing that you do when you want to get the value from dictionary that is var value = JsonObj[key]

Answer (score 13):

You may need:

```
Object.keys(JSON[0]);
```

To get something like:

```
[ 'amount', 'job', 'month', 'year' ]
```

---

*Note: Your JSON is invalid.*

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: Object.keys is not a function`

Answer (score 6):

Try out this

```
var str ="{ "name" : "user"}";
var jsonData = JSON.parse(str);     
console.log(jsonData.name)

//Array Object

str ="[{ "name" : "user"},{ "name" : "user2"}]";
jsonData = JSON.parse(str);     
console.log(jsonData[0].name)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply traverse through the object and return if a match is found.

Here is the code:

```
returnKeyforValue : function() {
    var JsonObj= { "one":1, "two":2, "three":3, "four":4, "five":5 };
        for (key in JsonObj) {
        if(JsonObj[key] === "Keyvalue") {
            return key;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you [parse the JSON representation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), it'll become a JavaScript [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of objects.

Because of this, you can use the [`.length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) of the JavaScript array to see how many elements are contained, and use a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop to enumerate it.