# How do I change a JSON object into an array key/value pairs through code?

Tags: javascript

How do I change a JSON object into an array key/value pairs through code?

**from:**

```
{
   'name':'JC',
   'age':22
}
```

**to:**

`['name':JC,'age':22] //actually, see UPDATE`

---

**UPDATE:**

...I meant:

`[{"name":"JC"},{"age":22}]`

Comment: That is an invalid array. Did you mean: `["name","JC","age",22]` or `[{"name":"JC"},{"age":22}]`?

Comment: Yes it is Rob! @Jan: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558981/iterating-through-list-of-keys-for-associative-array-in-json

Comment: To expand on @RobW's point, Javascript does not have associative arrays (like PHP), it uses objects. They have a few key limitations, but work in a very similar way. Maybe it would help to know why you are looking for this type of construct?

Comment: @Morgon: just out of curiosity actually..

Comment: @RobW: hmm... so if that's the case, how would I do that through code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you only want understand how to iterate it:

```
var obj = { 'name':'JC', 'age':22 };
for (var key in obj)
{
    alert(key + ' ' + obj[key]);
}
```

**Update:**
So you create an array as commented:

```
var obj = { 'name':'JC', 'age':22 };
var obj2 = [];
for (var key in obj)
{
    var element = {};
    element[key] = obj[key]; // Add name-key pair to object
    obj2.push(element);      // Store element in the new list
}
```

Comment: well I want to put it into one BIG array containing many objects.. like [{..},{..}] with one Object per property..

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to convert a JSON string into an object, you can use the built in JSON parser (although not in old browsers like IE7):

```
JSON.parse("{\"name\":\"JC\", \"age\":22}");
```

Note that you have to use double quotes for your JSON to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

There is no associative array in JavaScript. Object literals are used instead. Your JSON object is such literal already.