# Getting the keys of a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made an object like:

```
var courtdocument=    {
    'CFADocuments': {
        cv: [
            "CFA_Pack_Cover_Letter.docx",
            "Countersigned-CFA-Terms-and-Conditions-Letter.docx",
            "Test-cfa-documents - Copy - Copy.docx"
        ]
    },
    'LetterOfClaim': {
        cv: [
             "CFA_Pack_Cover_Letter.docx",
            "Countersigned-CFA-Terms-and-Conditions-Letter.docx"
        ]
    },
    'LetterOfInstruction': {
        cv: [
             "CFA_Pack_Cover_Letter.docx",
            "Countersigned-CFA-Terms-and-Conditions-Letter.docx"

        ]
    },
    Letters: {
        cv: [

        ]
    },
    'MedicalRecords': {
        cv: [

        ]
    },
    'medicalreports': {
        cv: [

        ]
    }
}
```

How will I get this set?

```
CFADocuments
LetterOfClaim
LetterOfInstruction
Letters
MedicalRecords
medicalreports
```

Comment: What is the question exactly ?

Comment: Please refer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558981/iterating-through-list-of-keys-for-associative-array-in-json

Comment: i want to get CFADocuments and etc all key values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for the different keys in the `courtdocument` obejct then in modern browsers you can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) - IE < 9 not supported you can use a shim as shown in the [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Compatibility)

```
console.log(Object.keys(courtdocument))
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VHqRU/)

Comment: Note, of course, that browsers that don't support `Object.keys` [can easily be shimmed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Compatibility).

Comment: @lonesomeday then how will i handle this

Comment: @Riturajratan By clicking on that link and doing what it says?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use `courtdocument.CFADocuments` or `courtdocument["CFADocuments"]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the set of values, try:

```
var result = []

for (var prop in courtdocument){
    if (courtdocument.hasOwnProperty(prop){
        result.push(courtdocument[prop])
    }
}
```