# Any way to update a JS object but leave previous fields untouched?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for something similar to the `$set` operator in Mongo and wasn't able to find it in the JS documentation:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

I want to replace the value of a field to another specified value. If the field does not exist, I want to add the field with the specified value. BUT if there are existing fields in the object already I don't want to overwrite them.

Say that I've got this:

```
var hashTable = { key1: "Original Stuff", key2: "More Stuff" }
```

I want to update `key2` to something else, but only `key2`. I want to leave `key1` alone. Additonally, I want to add in a `key3`. It would be nice if there some something like:

```
var hashTable = hashTable.set( {key2: "Edited Stuff", key3: "Added stuff"} )
```

hashTable would then be

`{ key1: "Original Stuff", key2: "Edited Stuff", key3: "Added Stuff" }`

**EDIT**

Imagine that the original object and the object I want to use as an updating parameter both have tons and tons of fields. I'm not going to be doing `hashTable.key2 = "Edited Stuff"`

Comment: So you want to update the value if it's preset in the new value right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're looking for the [`for..in` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558981/iterating-through-list-of-keys-for-associative-array-in-json), which lets you iterate over the keys of your object.

So in this case, you can easily write your function :

```
var setDict = function(target,extra){
    for(var property in extra){
         target[property]=extra[property];
    }
    return target;
}
```

Underscore.js also provides a function for this ([`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend)).

Usage :

```
var hashTable = { key1: "Original Stuff", key2: "More Stuff" }
hashTable = _.extend(hashTable,{key2: "Edited Stuff", key3: "Added stuff"} )
// hashTable == {key1: "Original Stuff", key2: "Edited Stuff", key3: "Added stuff"}
```

Comment: Right. The object could have like 100 fields. There's no way I'm going to write explicit code for each field that checks on each of those 100 fields.

Awesome... I didn't think to check in Underscore. I'll go try it right now.

Comment: WOOHOO `_.extend` was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Underscore has a lot of useful methods for general purpose operations in Javascript, always useful to flip through it to see if there's something that can fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

Simply do what you want:

```
var hashTable = { key1: "Original Stuff", key2: "More Stuff" }
hashTable.key2 = "Edited Stuff";
hashTable.key3 = "Added stuff";
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 0):

To extend Rudy's answer (I was typing something similar!).

If you need to get the keys dynamically you can always use the object['property'] notation as well.