# Hi , Please help me for How to convert data from {"rOjbectId":["abc","def","ghi","ghikk"]} to ["abc", "def", "ghi", "ghikk"] using ajax

Tags: ajax

Please help me for How to convert data from   {"rOjbectId":["abc","def",ghi","ghikk"]} to "["abc", "def", "ghi", "ghikk"] using ajax

Comment: Ajax isn't any programing language, Ajax stand Asynchronous JavaScript And XML

Answer (score 0):

Is this in javascript? Then you access the property:

```
var obj = {"rOjbectId":["abc","def","ghi","ghikk"]}
console.log(obj.rOjbectId)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Zedd, but i need to convert json to array as shown above : from {"rOjbectId":["abc","def",ghi","ghikk"]} to "["abc", "def", "ghi", "ghikk"]

Comment: {"rOjbectId":["abc","def","ghi","ghikk"]} is dynamic value , it will be change as user request and need response json object to array ["abc", "def", "ghi", "ghikk"]

Comment: well, my response shows how to do this. Your get the array if you access the rOjbectId property of your ajax response

Answer (score 0):

Assuming in javascript you need to access the property of your object. In this case `obj.rOjbectId`, or you can access it like this too: `obj['rOjbectId']`

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary = {"cats":[1,2,37,38,40,32,33,35,39,36], "dogs": [4,5,6,3,2]};
var k= Object.keys(dictionary);
```

then loop over k for different keys and you may get the vals like this

```
dictionary[k[0]]
```

part of solution taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9539168/2833695).Hope it helps

Comment: $(function() {
var result=[];
$.ajax({
 url: "http://localhost:8080/World/hello?name="+$("#tags").val(),
       success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert(data);
         var  availableTags=["abc", "def", "ghi", "ghikk"];
        $.each(availableTags, function( key, value ) {
           result.push(value);
         });
              } });
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
     source: result
    });
  });

Comment: here availableTags[] is hard coded to ["abc", "def", "ghi", "ghikk"] , 
  but same data is avilable in "data" as shown in alert in the form of "  {"rOjbectId":["abc","def",ghi","ghikk"]}  "
  i have to pass same data to result[].
  
  Please suggest me which one is better.

Comment: @satyanarayanabanisetti I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.But from what I understand this would be a different question.Moreover you want to know which one is better with what are you comparing this one?