# Javascript iterate over python dict

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am creating a python dictionary and passing it over to javascript.

```
var students = {{myStudents}}
```

when generated becomes

```
var students = [(u'Mark', u'b7'), (u'Phillipe', u'a67'), (u'John', u'a1')]
```

Now I need to loop over the names (Mark, Philippe, etc...) and populate a dropdown list.

My problem, how can I access the key/value separately. Ultimately I could pass both lists separately, but I want to check if their is another non-bruteforce way.

Comment: Why don't you JSON encode your dict?

Comment: What you have also looks like a list of tuples, not like a dict.

Comment: @jsfan Could you provide example? no idea why it looks like that!

Comment: A dictionary would render as `{u'Mark': u'b7', u'Phillipe': u'a67', u'John': u'a1'}`. However, neither what you have nor that would be valid Javascript because of the unicode markers.

Do you want to stick with the list of tuples or make it a dictionary?

Comment: There's some useful info about iterating over dictionaries in JavaScript [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/558981/4014959). In particular, you need to use the `.hasOwnProperty()` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have a dict in `myStudents`, you could write your template as:

```
var students = {{% for key, value in myStudents %}{"{{ key }}": "{{ value }}"},{% endfor %}}
```

which will become

```
var students = {"Mark": "b7", "Philippe": "a67", ...}
```

in your HTML source. You can then iterate it in Javascript using the following:

```
for(var key in students) {
  var value = students[key];
  ...
}
```

Comment: {"{{ key }}": "{{ value }}" },

Answer (score 1):

Before passing the variable to Javascript, you want to

```
import json
json_var = json.dumps(var)
```

and then pass `json_var` instead of `var` to the Javascript.

In Javascript you then iterate over it as

```
for (k in students) {
}
```

using `k` to get the names and `students[k]` to get the value associated with the name.

If you want to stick with your list of tuples, use the value `students[k][0]` in the loop for the names and `students[k][1]` for the second value in the tuple.

Comment: json.dumps is giving a pipe.broken error and increased loading time

Comment: @Syntax_Error: How large is your dictionary or list? Can you edit your question with some of the relevant Python code? I have JSON encoded pretty large objects before without having any performance trouble.

Comment: Around 6000 elements. Name could reach 60 chars and codes are 15 chars... I have simplified them in the question. Selcuk's answer is the best solution I think

Comment: @Syntax_Error: Selcuk's answer is ok as long as you have no double quotes in the strings. Those will break your Javascript. JSON encoding before passing is safer and better style. 6000 elements is definitely no problem and that you get a broken pipe tells me that you're doing something wrong somewhere. However, without seeing the code and context, I wouldn't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Like @jsfan pointed out, python dictionary would render as follows:
`{u'students': {u'Mark': u'b7', u'Phillipe': u'a67', u'John': u'a1'}}`. To iterate over the dictionary you use,

```
  for (x in students) {
    students[x]
 }
```

But if you wish to get value for a particular key, for example the value for key 'Mark', you use:

```
for (x in students)
 {
    students[x]['Mark']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answers here and it didn't work for me. I figured out that all I had to do is to parse the JSON data. I thought that sharing this solution might be helpful for others:
In the python file:

```
import json
json_data = json.dumps(your_dict)
```

pass the json_data to your Javascript file.
In your Javascript file:

```
var keys = JSON.parse(json_data);
for (var key in keys) {

}
```